# Fazer login alterando cookies

Tags: cookies

É possivel alterar os cookies de uma página para acessar outra conta? Por exemplo eu altero os cookies de um navegador com dados do outro

Comment: Sim é possível, ao usar o cookie de uma sessão de outra pessoa você basicamente está roubando a sessão dela. No caso você terá acesso à sessão dela sem precisar de usuário e senha.